# setting up cypress for different env when I have different baseUrl and apiUrl on all of them

Tags: angular, cypress, config, cypress-configuration

so I've been setting up my tests on localhost, but now I want to set them up to run on several different environments, but on all of them I have a separate baseUrl and apiUrl.
dev has: `http://base.url.com` and api: `http://base.url.com/api`
prod has: `https://prod.url.com` and api: `https://prod-api.url.com/v1`

I've read the documentation and some posts here(although a lot of them are from before cypress v10), but I can't decide what would be the best approach. I'm leaning towards creating different config files(cypress-dev.config.ts, cypress-prod.config.ts etc.), each for a different environment like so:

```
e2e: { 
  baseUrl: 'http://base.url.com', 
  env: { 
    apiURl: '..'  
}}
```

creating new npm scripts where I set cypress to use the correct config file when running on a particular environment.

I've considered using one config file, but I'm having trouble figuring out how exactly to do it.

```
e2e: {    env: { 
    development: { 
      baseUrl:'baseURlDev',
      apiURl: 'apiUrlDev'
    },
    production: {
      baseUrl:'baseURlProd',
      apiURl: 'apiUrlProd'
    },
    staging: {
      baseUrl:'baseURlStag'
      apiURl: 'apiUrlStag'   } 
    }}
```

and how to use this is my cypress code. Cypress.env('*type-of-environment*.baseUrl')?? I'm not clear on this.

Or maybe there's third neat way of doing this that I haven't considered yet?

Comment: I would expect using different config files and using fileReplacements in `angular.json` / `project.json` to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When Cypress v10 changed the configuration from `cypress.json` to `cypress.config.js`, one of the benefits was to allow javascript to be used in the config.

This means fiddly stuff that used to require external packages (like [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) for this kind of thing) are no longer needed.

This is how I would implement your `type-of-environment`

**cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      const envName = config.env['type-of-environment'] || 'development'
      const envType = config.env[envName] 
      config.baseUrl = envType.baseUrl;
      config.env.apiUrl = envType.apiUrl;
      return config
    },
    env: { 
      development: { 
        baseUrl:'http://baseURlDev',
        apiUrl: 'http://apiUrlDev'
      },
      production: {
        baseUrl:'http://baseURlProd',
        apiUrl: 'http://apiUrlProd'
      },
      staging: {
        baseUrl:'http://baseURlStag',
        apiUrl: 'http://apiUrlStag'   
      },
    }
  },
})
```

**package.json**

```js
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "cy:open": "cypress open",         // defaults to development
    "cy:prod": "cypress open --env type-of-environment=prod"
  }
}
```

Comment: awesome, this is just the kind of solution I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: One correction: first you have to grab the value of the variable from the command line, and then use it to get the correct property from config.env:             `const envName = config.env['type-of-enviroment'];
const envType = config.env[envName] || config.env.development;`

Comment: Yes I think you're right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`as-a`](https://github.com/bahmutov/as-a) to set up multiple env settings within a `.as-a.ini` only for your local and run a command to load those variables.

Install

```
npm install --global as-a
```

Create `.as-a.ini` file within your repo

```
touch ~/.as-a.ini
```

.as-a.ini file

```
[development]
baseUrl=https://dev.url.com
apiURl=https://dev.api.com
[production]
baseUrl=https://prod.url.com
apiURl=https://prod.api.com
```

Then you can use the run command like this `as-a [environment] npx cypress open`

```
// open with development variables
as-a development npx cypress open
```